# Start service at boot time and launch activity from onReceive method of BR

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, boot

First I wan't to say that I tried to find my answers on stackoverflow with no success. Second, I tested my code on my Samsung S3 4G 4.1.2.

I have some question with the code I produced.

**---Exlaination :**
The code starts ClsAutoStart at BOOT_COMPLETED, which starts a service, SvcFirst, which register a BroadcastReceiver synchronized with NEW_OUTGOING_CALL action. In the onReceive() method, I start the activity.

You understood that the activity is supposed to popup when the is a call (no condition yet).

**---Questions :**
This works but I DO NOT have the exact expected behaviour so I have some questions :

1- Everything goes well ONLY if I first open the activity AFTER installation and BEFORE reboot. Then, after that, every piece of code does what it has to. Could anyone explain me why I have to launch the activity in order it to work ? How to avoid it ?

2- The reason why I use this method to do things is because I don't want my application to appear in the application list (for the user). I wan't the activity to be launched by the onReceive method.
I tried to remove the following lines from the manifest file but I go back to question "1" : if I can't previously launch the activity, it doesn't work (no possibility to launch anything because the lines are removed).

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Could anyone explain me why I doesn't work and how to correct it ?
Is this the correct way to do "hide" my application ?
On stackoverflow, I found many answers ... this is one of them (question "3" is one of the others ...).

3- I removed the previous lines (question "2) and add the following one in the receiver section (of BOOT_COMPLETED action) in my manifest file but it still doesn't change anything. Any clue ?

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

**---Code :**

**manifest file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.frontal.invisible04"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.frontal.invisible04.ActMain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_act_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.frontal.invisible04.SvcFirst">
        </service>

        <receiver 
            android:name="com.frontal.invisible04.ClsAutoStart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />-->
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>        
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**ClsAutoStart :**

```
public class ClsAutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {    
   if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
    {
     context.startService(new Intent(context, SvcFirst.class));      
    }         
  }
}
```

**SvcFirst :**

```
public class SvcFirst extends Service
{
 Context context;
 private BroadcastReceiver br_interface;
 private static final String ACTION_SHOWACT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";

 @Override
 public void onCreate()
  {
   super.onCreate();   
   this.context = getApplicationContext(); 
  }

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
  {
   final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction(ACTION_SHOWACT);   
   this.br_interface = new SecretInterfaceBR();
   this.registerReceiver(this.br_interface, filter);
   return (START_STICKY);
  } 

 public class SecretInterfaceBR extends BroadcastReceiver 
  {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
     Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ActMain.class);
     intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
     context.startActivity(intent1);
    }
  }

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
  { 
   return (null);
  } 

 public void onDestroy()
  {
   this.unregisterReceiver(this.br_interface); 
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone explain me why I have to launch the activity in order it to work ?

Because manifest-registered receivers will not work while the app is in a force-stopped state, as of Android 3.1. That occurs:

- On first install
- After the user taps the "Force Stop" button in Settings

> How to avoid it ?

Only support Android 3.0 and below. Note that this is a diminishing percentage of the Android device market.

> Could anyone explain me why I doesn't work and how to correct it ?

See above.

> Is this the correct way to do "hide" my application ?

What you are describing does not hide an application, but merely represents an application with no launcher icon. Such applications typically are not useful as of Android 3.1, due to the aforementioned force-stopped restriction. And, these applications are still listed everywhere else that chooses to list applications, such as the Settings app.

> I removed the previous lines (question "2) and add the following one in the receiver section (of BOOT_COMPLETED action) in my manifest file but it still doesn't change anything. Any clue ?

A `<category>` is rarely used with a receiver. The `HOME` category is used with activities and designates a home screen implementation.

Comment: @frontal: "Is there a way to register receiver (BOOT_COMPLETED) outside of the manifest file ?" -- not really. While you could call `registerReceiver()` from some running component, by the time that component can make that call, the boot will have long since passed. "In my case, on the first install, I can't run anything because there is nothing to run" -- then you will need to fix that. Besides, you need to give the users the ability to control the behavior of your app, access to documentation, a copy of the license agreement, support links, etc.

Comment: I accidentally suppressed my previous comment. Thanks for your answer. You said that I have to fix that. I understand you but here I don't want my application to be launched thanks to an icon but thanks to a special event (a call for exemple). Is there a good way to do that ? I see that you are very precise but I need you to be more.

Comment: @frontal: "Is there a good way to do that ?" -- not in a way that avoids the need for something to explicitly launch your app to move it out of the force-stopped state. For example, you could use GCM to send a push message, or watch for an SMS message, or whatever. But, as with `BOOT_COMPLETED`, none of those will work while your app is in the force-stopped state.

Comment: I understand that I have to move out of the force-stopped state. I also understand that I can send a sms or whatever to move out of that state. But what will receive this event (sms or whatever) if no code is executed previously (the receiver) ? When I create a project with only one class (called at boot time) that starts a service, I don't have any launch icon. I understand why (no activity). It works (the service is finally started). I thought that I could add an activity which could be launched by some code in my project.

Comment: @frontal: "I also understand that I can send a sms or whatever to move out of that state" -- the *only* thing that moves you out of that state is an *explicit* `Intent` (i.e., one that has your `ComponentName` in it). An SMS receiver will not qualify. The most common scenario of an app being started by somebody else via an explicit `Intent` is a launcher starting your `LAUNCHER` activity. You are welcome to try to find something else, but, as I pointed out, you need a `LAUNCHER` activity for other reasons anyway.